# Why does the website Anime Planet say that there are only 13 episodes of Natsume's book of friends, when CrunchyRoll has 39 episodes?

Tags: crunchyroll, natsumes-book-of-friends, anime-planet

I'm just a little confused. I just want to make sure I watch everything in the correct order and such. Why does the website Anime Planet say that there are only 13 episodes of Natsume's book of friends, when CrunchyRoll has 39 episodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Natsume is divided up into 4 seasons. You can see the rest of them at the bottom of the [anime-planet page](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/natsume-yuujinchou):

[image]

It's similar with [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=9419).

But Crunchyroll has them grouped together under one listing (but for some shows, the different seasons are listed within the show's page). They do that with a lot of multi-season shows, perhaps in an effort to make the favorites/queues work easier so you don't have to hunt down different listings for different seasons of the same show.

Comment: For the record, there is also a 5th season now, "Natsume Yuujinchou Go"

Answer (score 7):

The seasons are named differently:

Anime Planet has:

- [**Natsume Yuujinchou**](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/natsume-yuujinchou)
- [**Zoku Natsume Yuujinchou**](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/zoku-natsume-yuujinchou#)
- [**Natsume Yuujinchou San**](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/natsume-yuujinchou-san)
- [**Natsume Yuujinchou Shi**](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/natsume-yuujinchou-shi)

And CrunchyRoll splits them as:

- [**Natsume Yuujinchou**](http://www.crunchyroll.com/natsume-yujin-cho)
- [**Natsume Yuujinchou Shi**](http://www.crunchyroll.com/natsume-yujin-cho-shi)

For some reason

Comment: In other words, Crunchyroll bunches the first 3 seasons into one listing, numbered episodes 1-39.  This can be broken down by your mind as three 13-episode seasons.  Season Five is now available also, and catalogued as [Natsume Yuujinchou Go](http://www.crunchyroll.com/natsume-yujin-cho-5).  "Go" is replaced by 5, though, and I have kept spelling consistent with what Toshinou wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Natsume Yuujinchou have a many of season.
Until now there are 5 season
and every season approximately have 11 until 13 
And there are a change with picture on season 5 because Natsume Yuujinchou move studio from brain base to Shuka studio.
And they are say on 2017 NY will have season 6